# Is it possible to sum up time field in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

[image: Example]

I have 3 time(0) column in 1 row. I want to calculate arrival-Time column automatically and this is result of the sum of `Departure-Time + Duration`

```
Departure-Time= 14:30:00
Duration:     =  02:45:00
Arrival must be = 17:15:00
```

is it possible with trigger or computed area method? thanks in advance

Comment: Please tag the appropriate database. SQL is the standard query language and not a database. The answer to your question depends on the database that you are using.

Comment: Sure, but this is not a "Do it for me service" We need to know what you tried and where you encountered any problems.

Comment: Time _field_? A time value has an hours field, a minutes field and a seconds field.

Comment: The `time` type is designed for storing a *time of day*, not a *time span*. Those are distinct concepts, and it doesn't make *sense* to add times of day together.

Comment: @jarlh no, it doesn't; individual values in SQL *do not have* "fields"; a time field is just an integer, ultimately - with some meaning behind the underlying value (also: the precision of `time` goes deeper than just seconds)

Comment: @MarcGravell, "_There are three classes of datetime data types defined within this part of ISO/IEC 9075:_ [...] _— TIME — contains the <primary datetime field>s HOUR, MINUTE, and SECOND._" ISO/IEC 9075-2:2016(E), section 4.6 Datetimes and intervals.

Comment: @jarlh that's nice but irrelevant; the SQL Server `time` type  is defined to 100ns: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/time-transact-sql (or 1ms in Infomatica)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server does not support direct addition on `time` values; however, you can use `datediff` against `0` to find how many (of some interval - minutes, seconds, etc; choice depends on your required precision) to calculate the duration, and then `dateadd` the same:

```sql
declare @start time= '14:30:00', @duration time = '02:45:00';

declare @end time = dateadd(second, datediff(second, 0, @duration), @start);

select @end; -- 17:15:00.0000000
```

Comment: it is useful for me. i had to do a lot of time difference calculations but this is new for me. now i can focus on this example thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE #SomeTimes
(
    Departure TIME,
    Duration TIME
)

INSERT INTO #SomeTimes
VALUES ('14:30:00', '02:45:00')

SELECT Departure, Duration, DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, Duration) , Departure)
FROM #SomeTimes
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data is in a table.  You can add a computed column to the table so the arrival time is always calculated correctly:

```
alter table t add column arrival_time as
    (convert(time, convert(datetime, departure_time) + convert(datetime, duration));
```

This way, the value is always correct when you query the table.

Note:  For some inexplicable reason, SQL Server allows you to add `datetime` values, but not `time` values (and other combinations).  This also works across midnight, so `23:00:00 + 02:00:00` is `01:00:00`, rather than generating an error.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sharing an easy way solution for my case. You can follow the pictures. Thanks everyone.

[image: Computed area script]

[image: After the input only duration and dep. time]

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to directly SUM a Time Column. However, if you want to SUM up a duration across rows i.e. a Time(7) data type you can convert the time to seconds (or milliseconds), do the sum and then convert back to a Time.

```
CAST(DATEADD(SECOND, SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, '1900-01-01', CAST(YOUR_DURATION_TIME_COLUMN AS DATETIMEOFFSET))), 0) AS TIME(7))
    
CAST(DATEADD(MILLISECOND, SUM(DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, '1900-01-01', CAST(YOUR_DURATION_TIME_COLUMN AS DATETIMEOFFSET))), 0) AS TIME(7))
```